# How to use relay shield to control dc motor speed and direction?

Tags: motor, relay

I tried l298n before but its output voltage wasn't high

so I use relay shield but  it seems that the car can only go forward or stop

Can I control the speed and direction of dc motors?

Comment: Please can you expand on your question?  What do you motors need V and A?

Comment: You can change the polarity of the power going to the motor using only a single DPDT relay. You'd need a second relay to turn the motor on and off. Using a relay to control speed will wear out the relay pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Using a mechanical relay to control the speed is not a good idea. But you can control the directions.

I prefer you to use Solid state relays (SSR) to do this. Arrange 4 SSR as Hbridge and Use PWM to control the speed.

refer [this](http://www.power-io.com/library/appnotes/h-bridge.htm)

or you can use the devices like [this](http://www.crydom.com/en/tech/newsletters/jan%202013%20-%20solid%20statements%20-%20dc%20motor%20reversing.pdf) which has direction control as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the easiest way is by using a "motor shield".  There are more options than just L298N.

Are you sure it was the voltage that wasn't high enough, its normally the current (Amps)?

To do it with a relay you need to change the polarity of the feeds to the motor.  You could do this with 2 relays both connected all the time, but if you close the wrong one, you will short everything.  It would be better using a motor controller.

Comment: When I used l298n the output  voltage  was about 4.6V current was 

about 120~130mA

Comment: the fast speed occurred when I connect 5V pin of arduino to the 

positive of motor and GND pin to the negative of motor 

I measured the current was about 120~130mA

Comment: But I used  the 9V battery to connect logic 5V of l298N ,the speed

didn't increase. I am sure I connected I don't know why it didn't work

Comment: Would this be better?
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield-v2-for-arduino/library-reference?view=all

Comment: 9V batteries can't provide a lot of power/current.

Comment: But i use 9V series 9V (18V)  it also seemed no difference to speed

Answer (score 0):

Most refer to [relays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) when talking about mechanical devices which are either closed or open.  If you arrange several in an H-bridge configuration, you can make you car go forward, stop and reverse.  But controlling speed is not possible.

Comment: Ok thank you it seems the only choice is l298n